# How to add sound/vibration to remote push notification in Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, apple-push-notifications, firemonkey, kinvey

I followed the great Sarina tutorial about showing Kinvey push notifications on my Android app.

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2014/04/16/remote-push-notifications-on-android-with-rad-studio-xe6/

Everything works awesome now, but ... I have a detail which makes the push notifications useless.

The problem is that they do not play any sound or vibrate when arriving to my phone :(
So, I never realize that they arrived.

Sarina aswered something about the solution only on iOS, but I do not know how to write ios code on Delphi or how to handle that. And in case I do it, I am leaving Android with the problem.

So, I would like to play a sound with that notification.
Does anybody know how can I play a sound/vibrate when the push notification arrives? Or at least a workaround which could help me?

Thanks!